# How to "convert" a php soap code to xml?

Tags: php, xml, soap

I have this code:

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://soapserver.example.com/blahblah.asmx?wsdl");

// Prepare SoapHeader parameters
$sh_param = array(
                'Username'    =>    'username',
                'Password'    =>    'password');
$headers = new SoapHeader('http://soapserver.example.com/webservices', 'UserCredentials', $sh_param);
```

How can see the xml code of $headers?

Well, if maybe you don't understand me check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3105577/simple-php-soapclient-example-for-paypal-needed) out. As you can see the person who asks show a "soap code" and then shows the corresponding xml. That what I want, gets the corresponding xml code.

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 1):

have you tried this function ? : $soapClient->__getLastRequestHeaders()

for this you need to active "trace" option like this :

```
$soapClient = new SoapClient("https://soapserver.example.com/blahblah.asmx?wsdl", array('trace' => 1));
```